# Opening a file in downloads folder Android N(API 24+)

Tags: android

All I wanted was to open a pdf file in my External Downloads Directory.

I used this code to open the file, and it used to work fine.

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getPath()
            + File.separator + filename);
    Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
    Intent pdfOpenintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    pdfOpenintent.setDataAndType(path, "application/" + getExtension(filename));
    pdfOpenintent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    try {
        CourseModulesActivity.this.startActivity(pdfOpenintent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        pdfOpenintent.setType("application/*");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(pdfOpenintent, "No Application found to open File - " + filename));
    }
```

Now in android N(API 24+), it crashes saying `android.os.FileUriExposedException`

I followed the link - https://stackoverflow.com/a/38858040/4788557 and https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/share-file.html#ShareFile to convert my code to this -

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getPath()
            + File.separator + filename);
    Uri path = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file);
    Intent pdfOpenintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    pdfOpenintent.setData(path);
    pdfOpenintent.setType("application/" + getExtension(filename));
    pdfOpenintent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    pdfOpenintent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    try {
       CourseModulesActivity.this.startActivity(pdfOpenintent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        pdfOpenintent.setType("application/*");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(pdfOpenintent, "No Application found to open File - " + filename));
    }
```

and added provider xml as -

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

and manifest as -

```
<manifest...>
....
<application...>
....
    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>
....
</application>
```

So, now the app doesn't crash on N, but the pdf applications are unable to open the file.
 Any help in this direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I used this code to open the file, and it used to work fine.

There are at least two bugs in that code:

- `"application/" + getExtension(filename)` is not an appropriate algorithm for finding the MIME type for a file, as not all MIME types begin with `application/` (e.g., `image/jpeg`, `text/plain`). Use `MimeTypeMap`.
- [`setType()` clears the data previously set on the `Intent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setType(java.lang.String)), so your `Intent` has no `Uri`.

Plus, do not use concatenation to build a file path, as your code does not handle the case where somebody decided to have `DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS` end in a `/`. Replace:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getPath()
        + File.separator + filename);
```

with:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), fiename);
```

> but the pdf applications are unable to open the file

There is no `Uri` in your `Intent`, as your second code snippet contains the same bug as does the first code snippet. Use `setDataAndType()` to set both the `Uri` and the MIME type at one time. Or, just use `setData()` and get rid of `setType()`, as `FileProvider` will use `MimeTypeMap` to determine a MIME type.

FWIW, [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ContentProvider/V4FileProvider) demonstrates using `FileProvider` to serve a PDF file to PDF viewers.

Comment: those are all specifically application type pdf/xlxs etc files... 
The real bug was `setDataAndType()` 

Thanks.